# wordpress use_smilies option not exists on writing settings page

Tags: emoji, smilies

My emoticons like :-) and :P not converted to images after trying to check the user_smiles option in writing settings page I found that the checkbox option does not exist on the page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gouaX.jpg

NOTE: I found that the option exists on the database and its value is 1.

NOTE: I deleting everything and install the WordPress again without changing any settings or themes or plugins and the problem not fixed.

Comment: have you tried with a default WP theme ? Maybe the theme you're using is hiding the option ?

Comment: Yes, i trying the default theme, I found that all sites that using WordPress the last version have this problem. Emojies are not converted into images.

Answer (score 4):

As noted on [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Smilies), the option was removed in 4.3

> As of WordPress 4.3, the option to disable graphic smileys was removed
>   from new installs. There is [a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/keep-emoticons-as-text/) if you want to retain the
>   option.

Comment: Yes Jacob but this plugin will convert emoji to text and that's what happens with me this is the problem I want emoji to convert into images, not text, I can't really solve the problem I install a pure WordPress without using any plugin or another theme and the problem not solving.